# DataInputStream shows 0 data length

Tags: java

I have created a client to receive data from socket and trying to store the data to a char array.
This is how I am trying to do this.

```
...     
public void run() {
        try {

           DataInputStream m_DataInputStream = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()); //s is socket object
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            while ((msg = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(msg+" >msg");

                try {
                    m_DataInputStream.readByte();
                    int len = available();
                    System.out.println("datalength "+len);
                    char[] c = new char[len];
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < len) {
                        c[i] = (char) m_DataInputStream.readByte();
                        //System.out.print(c);
                        i++;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (msg.equals("Server is Shutting Down")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            s.close();
            br.close();
            m_DataInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception E) {
            System.out.println(E+" :in Threadrecieve run method");
        }
    }

   public int available() {
    try {
        return m_DataInputStream.available();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that every second time the length of m_DataInputStream shows 0. Please help to identify what I am doing wrong.

Comment: 'every second time' of what?

Comment: Don't mix binary and text, it just leads to confusion unless you *really* know what you are doing.

Comment: When reading from a socket, you should not just read whatever is available as assume it means anything. You cannot assume you can read the same number of bytes in the same manner as they were written.

Comment: Is there any reason to discard a byte after you read a line? Is there any reason to wait for some data after the server has told you it is shutting down?

Comment: Reading from two different wrappers of the same InputStream is almost guaranteed not to produce correct results.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved my problem. Just removed the DataInputStream and looping using while (i < msg.length()) {
                            c[i] = msg.charAt(i);
                            i++;
                        }